# Does HTML tags within PHP code work?

Tags: php, sql, html, tags

I am using php to echo a bunch of text from a table in my database. The problem is, the text I am printing by php are poems and I need to have line breaks to separate different lines. (ONE poem is stored in a cell of a table)

My question is does the code below work? i.e. Can the `<br>` tag work? If it doesn't, what can I do to produce the intended results?

(I haven't set up my php so I cant test it myself...) Thanks in advance!

```
<?php
   echo "To drift with every passion till my soul <br> 
         Is a stringed lute on which all winds can play, <br>
         Is it for this that I have given away <br>
         Mine ancient wisdom, and austere control? <br> ";
?>
```

Comment: You should set up PHP first so that you can try this on your own and do some self-learning.

Comment: Try. It. And. See. What. Happens.

Comment: "I haven't set up the PHP to test it myself"... Why not?

Comment: That's the entire point of PHP... Consider the CSS `white-space: pre` instruction, too.

Comment: @ScottMcGready Actually I am setting up the database now and i am creating a SQL table and i thought about this question about line breaks...(Just how should i save the poems into the table) I havent learn anything about PHP so forgive my silly question

Comment: It's not a silly question, it just isn't stack overflow quality. We don't mind helping, it's just we do ask you try it first and let us know where you're stuck. Otherwise it just looks like you're wanting us to do coding for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can use html code inside php using echo function. here's an [example](http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/qt/php_with_html.htm)
This [link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.firstpage.php) from the manual might help you understand better.

```
 <?php 
 Echo "<html>";
 Echo "<title>HTML with PHP</title>";
 Echo "<b>My Example</b>";

 //your php code here

 Print "<i>Print works too!</i>"; 
 ?>
```

Comment: Please quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: Thanks! This really helps... now i know PHP is really powerful

Answer (score 0):

Yes -- To be exact, anything you echo will work, including JavaScript to be precise.